# For loop not getting executed

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have the following code snippet in which I'm trying to print some statements into an XML file:

```
void parseXML::writeStruct(std::fstream& abc,std::string prnt)
{
    for (map<string,struct structSet>::iterator it = structData.begin();it != structData.end();it++)
    {
      if (((it->second.parent.compare("")==0) && (it->second.written == false)))
      {
        bool write = true;
        if (it->second.type.compare("")==0)
        {
            for (set<std::string>::iterator i = it->second.fields.begin(); i != it->second.fields.end(); i++)
            {
                map<string,struct fieldSet>::iterator fd = fieldData.find(*i);
                if (fd != fieldData.end())
                {
                    std::string type = fd->second.type;
                    map<string,struct structSet>::iterator ntC = structData.find(type);
                    if (ntC != structData.end())
                    {
                        if (ntC->second.type.compare("") != 0)
                        {
                           map<string,struct structSet>::iterator ntC = structData.find(ntC->second.type);
                           if (ntC == structData.end()|| ntC->second.type.compare("")!= 0||ntC->second.written == false)
                           {  
                              continue;
                           }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            map<string,struct structSet>::iterator ntC = structData.find(ntC->second.type);
                            if (ntC->second.parent.compare(it->second.name))
                            {
                            }
                            else if (ntC->second.written == true)
                            {
                                abc << INDENT << "\t" <<"\t" << "<nonterminal ref= \"" << ntC->second.name.c_str() << "\">" << std::endl;
                                abc << INDENT << "\t" << "\t" <<"\t" << "<name>" << fd->second.name.c_str() << "</name>" << std::endl;
                                abc << INDENT << "\t"<< "\t" << "</nonterminal >" << std::endl;
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

The problem is that it is not executing the first `for` loop:

```
for (map<string,struct structSet>::iterator it = structData.begin(); it != structData.end(); it++)
```

What are the possible reasons for this?

Comment: The only possible reason is: `structData` is empty.

Comment: Your indentation is all over the place.  clean it up if possible.

Comment: Might I recommend some refactoring?  [Arrow code](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html) is difficult to comprehend, difficult to debug, and difficult to maintain.

Comment: if your problem is the very first line, you don't have to post the rest of the loop. also putting there some debug message (`cout` with `endl`) will let people know that you actually verified, that it doesn't get executed (and btw.. are you sure that your app actually called this function?)

Comment: @KirilKirov, there are other possibilities, but they are very remote.

Comment: @KirilKirov +1. Try printing `structData.size()`.

Comment: May I recommend you to use a real dom framework? Will make things a lot easier for you. You could e.g check out Poco (http://pocoproject.org/slides/170-XML.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a (hopefully) full list, sorry for the obvious entries, but we have no idea how experienced you are:

- `structData` is empty
- `structData` is corrupted, which crashes the application
- `parseXML::writeStruct` was never executed
- the for loop got executed, but the following (`if`, `for`) conditionals failed, and you interpreted this wrongly.

Pick a debugger or add trace messages (don't forget to use `endl` as output is typically line buffered and will be lost in case of a crash).

Note: *post only the relevant part of the code, the rest of it is just noise for us (unless you want a code review for which there is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)*